# How to proper use QCommandLineOption?

Tags: qt, command-line

How should I use CommandLineOption to process command line arguments
when the arguments are defined in the string?
For example, if the argument is "p ttt" I want to do one thing, if it is "p mmmm"
I need to do something else. My little test show nothing in debug.
Am I misunderstanding the usage of these classes?

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QCommandLineOption>
#include <QCommandLineParser>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
   QCommandLineParser parser;

    QCommandLineOption co({{"p","pp","t"}, "test option", "v1"});
    parser.addOption(co);

    parser.process ( (QStringList() << "p --v1"));
    QString vv = parser.value("p");
    qDebug() << vv;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QCommandLineOption>
#include <QCommandLineParser>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
   QCommandLineParser parser;

   QCommandLineOption co({"p","pp","t"}, "test option", "v1");
   parser.addOption(co);

   parser.process ( *a );
   QString vv = parser.value(co);
   qDebug() << vv;

   return a.exec();
}
```